# grouping rows into sections or groups IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

i am working on a Xcode 5.0.2 . i am following  these [lynda tutorials](http://www.lynda.com/iOS-tutorials/iOS-App-Development-Essential-Training/159179-2.html). the problem is  i am not able to create section or groups of tableView as in one of the video.. i have changed table view to grouped too,but it is displaying only one section.

here is my code

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSDictionary *courseDetails;
    NSArray *justCourseNames;

    NSDictionary *webCourseDetails;
    NSArray *webCourseNames; 
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return 2; 
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    if(section==0) {
        return @"iOS Courses";
    } else {
        return @"Web Courses";
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{  
    if(section==0) {
        return courseDetails.count;
    } else {
        return webCourseDetails.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{     
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"]; /

    if(indexPath.section==0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = justCourseNames[indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = webCourseNames[indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"courses" withExtension:@"plist"];
    courseDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];
    justCourseNames = courseDetails.allKeys; 

    NSURL *urlWeb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"courses_web" withExtension:@"plist"];
    webCourseDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:urlWeb];
    webCourseNames = webCourseDetails.allKeys;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you sure that both of the sections have rows in them? What happens if you put a breakpoint in viewDidLoad and log the courseDetails, justCourseNames, webCourseDetails and webCourseNames?

Comment: @davidRinnqvist yes i am sure .. infact i tried the same plist file in 2nd row too ..

Comment: if you use the xcode then check the properties of uitableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the simulator which wasn't populating all rows.

I have restarted the simulator and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in the code provided. Just make sure you set the dataSource to your tableView. In storyboard the easiest way is to control-drag from the tableView to the ViewController in the object outline and select dataSource from the menu on release.

Comment: i think i figure out the problem .. its the simulator issue .. scroll bar is ending but i have the content below too ..means there are rows which are not displaying ..